# Glob pattern to match filenames that does not have "." character

Tags: javascript, glob

What is the glob pattern to include filenames that end with `.test.js` but do not include filenames with additional `.` characters?

For example:

```
deviceFilter.test.js                      //pass
deviceFilter.offline.test.js              //fail
deviceFilter.nodata.test.js               //fail
deviceFilter.offline.nodata.test.js       //fail
```

With regex one can do `^[^.]*.test.js$` to achieve this. Is there any glob pattern equivalent? I have tried `*(!.)*.test.js` but this still passes all the examples above.

Comment: Bash has extended globbing that may be able to do this, but traditional glob syntax doesn't.

Comment: Since you're using JavaScript, why don't you just use a regexp?

Comment: That's because this is for configuring cypress testing framework the files to include, and unfortunately they only accept glob patterns not regex

Comment: Do they have a list of patterns to exclude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
+(!(*.*)).test.js
```

Tested with [this tool](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2B%28%21%28%2A.%2A%29%29.test.js&matches=false&tests=deviceFilter.test.js&tests=whatever&tests=deviceFilter.offline.test.js&tests=deviceFilter.nodata.test.js&tests=deviceFilter.offline.nodata.test.js)